# what does "confess" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have been reading A History of Britain and encountered this sentence,

> Sparks flew between them, kindling a fire of mutual recrimination. Henry accused Simon of provoking insurrection and made it clear that he would not 'keep covenant with a traitor', but de Montfort spoke back to the king as if he were a peer, upbraiding and even threatening him,...At another point Simon glared furiously at Henry and asked him if he had ***been confessed***, since he seemed no Christen at all.

I'm confused. Shouldn't the sentence use the active voice to mean 'confess a sin'?

Answer (score 3):

It's just a definition of "confess" that you're not yet acquainted with.

> [confess](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/confess):
>
> 4. (of a priest) to hear the confession of (a person)

So Simon asked Henry if a priest had ever heard his confession.